# How to have your app work offline from the start

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, offline-mode

I am looking for examples/tutorials or an explanation of how I can use my app that has both Firebase Authentication and the Firestore cloud database.  I think I understand how to setup offline persistence with the Firestore db, and I think that means that data will be persisted while my app is running and should connection be lost.

What if a user jumps on a a plane with zero connection and wants to run my app and is first presented with the login screen for Authentication.  Can you point to an example or tutorial on the best way to setup this so that the app can still run from the beginning with no connectivity and then be able to authenticate and put the data in the Firestore cloud database when connectivity is gained?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Firebase [**documentation**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-offline-behavior):

> If your app uses Firebase Authentication, the Firebase Realtime
>   Database client persists the user's authentication token across app
>   restarts. If the auth token expires while your app is offline, the
>   client pauses write operations until your app re-authenticates the
>   user, otherwise the write operations might fail due to security rules.

---

### EDIT:

You can achieve that with **Cloud Firestore** by enabling offline persistence:

> Cloud Firestore supports **offline data persistence**. This feature caches
>   a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so
>   your app can access the data when the device is offline. You can
>   **write**, **read**, **listen** to, and **query** the cached data. When the device
>   comes back online, Cloud Firestore synchronizes any local changes made
>   by your app to the Cloud Firestore backend.

Note that you won't need to make any changes to the code that you use to access Cloud Firestore data.
 
[**Here**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) you can see some examples for configuring the offline persistence.

Comment: Thanks.  The app is using Firestore Cloud DB not the RTB.  I will look to see if Firestore does the same thing.

Comment: @TO15108, my bad. I have updated my answer. Please let me know if it helps.